# How to make a settings file in a webpack project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, single-page-application

I'm making a SPA with Vue and Webpack, And I'm unsure about what the 'industry standard' (if there is one) for doing a settings file for the app.

Similar to appsettings.json in a .netcore project.

Ideally this needs to be able to easily use switch between different environments eg. config.dev.js / config.prod.js ect.
based on the environment mode passed to webpack on build.

Thanks.

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

Comment: @DigitalDrifter that works with the vue-cli-service rather webpack. Is there an example like this, but when running with webpack-dev-server and building with webpack?

Comment: Vue cli uses webpack, is there a reason not to be using it? It's quite a convenient tool as it provides most of the needed webpack config out of the box.